# Filter array in its didSet

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

for learning propose, Im working on a todo app
here is the model:

```
class Activity: Codable {
var title = ""
var isDone = false

convenience init(title: String) {
    self.init()
    self.title = title
}
}
```

And call the array of this class like that in the controller

```
var activity = [Activity]() {
    didSet {
        activity.filter({!$0.isDone})
    }
 }
```

as You can see, I added a filter in the didset to not show the todos that their `isDone == true`, but it give me a warning

```
Result of call to 'filter' is unused
```

How Can I fix it? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that as it says the result from the call to the function filter is unused. If you want to change the variable “activity” you should replace it with:

```
activity = activity.filter {!$0.isDone}
```